# Auto Start Python GUI

Tags: boot

I want to start openbox and autolaunch a custom python GUI i created on powerup.

Currently I manually launch by using xinit ./mystarter which contains the command to launch openbox and a path to my app.

Answer (score 0):

For lunching items to run on boot I use http://supervisord.org/
To install on your pi if your using a Debian distribution run:
`sudo apt-get install supervisor`